# Angular load child module in child routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular13

I have below routing module as parent.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BaseRoutingComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: {
      expectedRoles: ["superadmin", "admin", "office", "fieldrep", "salesperson"]
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: AdminDashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        data: {
          expectedRoles: ["superadmin", "admin", "office", "fieldrep", "salesperson"]
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'upload-tools',
        loadChildren: () => import('././modules/uploads/uploads.module').then(m =>
          m.UploadsModule),
        data: { 'preload': true }
      },
      {
        path: 'abc/:id',
        component: AbcComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        data: {
          expectedRoles: ["superadmin", "admin"]
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            loadChildren: () => import('./modules/bcd.module').then(m =>
              m.BcdModule),
          }
        ]
      },
   }]
```

And below routing as child

```
routes =   [{
    path: 'kkk',
    component: KKKComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: {
      expectedRoles: ["superadmin", "admin"]
    },
    {
    path: 'nnn',
    component: NNNComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: {
      expectedRoles: ["superadmin", "admin"]
    }]
```

but below path is not found :
abc/1/kkk -> KKKComponent
abc/1/nnn -> NNNComponent

If i added anything in child path (ex. `path: 'kb'`) then its accessible.
but i want `path: ''` .
So how can i achieve this?

Comment: could you try removing pathMatch: 'full' from the children declaration?

Comment: yes but without that, it loads default AbcComponent. @Andrei

Comment: your children path should be `''` instead of `'kkk'`. And in the parent, the route should not be `''`, but `'kkk'`

Comment: @Random but in child I have more than one routes. imagine in child kkk, mmm, nnn routes is there.

Comment: your child must have only 1 empty route, which may include any number of children.

Comment: Do we agree in your code, the route 'abc/1/kkk' must load the ABCComponent, and inside this component, there is a `<router-outlet>` in which will be injected KKKComponent ?

Comment: No i have only one <router-outlet> in my parent component. @Random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child route must be empty, but you may add any children. But here, the issue is that in your parent, the lazy route is empty. So it will actually load whenever the `'abc/:id'` is matched. So it is actually attached to the lazy module. So you could actually put that component in the child.

This is the child routing:

```
  {
    path: '',
    // AuthGuardService guard already executed on parent route
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: AbcComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        data: {
          expectedRoles: ["superadmin", "admin"]
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'kkk',
        component: KKKComponent,
        data: {
          expectedRoles: ["superadmin", "admin"]
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'nnnn',
        component: NNNComponent,
        data: {
          expectedRoles: ["superadmin", "admin"]
        }
      }]
  }
```

And rewrite the parent route (erases and replaces the whole content of your question, not just part of it):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BaseRoutingComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: {
      expectedRoles: ["superadmin", "admin", "office", "fieldrep", "salesperson"]
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: AdminDashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        data: {
          expectedRoles: ["superadmin", "admin", "office", "fieldrep", "salesperson"]
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'upload-tools',
        loadChildren: () => import('././modules/uploads/uploads.module').then(m =>
          m.UploadsModule),
        data: { 'preload': true }
      },
      {
        path: 'abc/:id',
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/bcd.module').then(m =>
          m.BcdModule),
      }
   }]
```

Comment: I have added whole routing, so please check your answer.

Comment: @AnantDoshi I added full parent route. But what is the expected route for "kkk" ? is it "abc/1/kkk" ? but you don't expect it to match the "AbcComponent" ?

Comment: yes it is "abc/1/kkk" and it must be match with KKKComponent. @Random

Comment: k, so that's a strange pattern if "/abc/1/kkk" should not match AbcComponent. You have to make them separate routes then, with a patchMatch: full. Please see my edited answer